# INotifyPropertyChanged event not firing when Observable Collection changed in WPF in VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I'm trying to use databinding in WPF with an MVVM pattern.  So far, it seems that everything is plumbed up properly and I'm using the right type of classes and objects.  My observable collection loads to first time correctly, but won't refresh on the datagrid when it changes.  Observable Collections should automatically implement INPC and I've also provided a handler for it in my base class, so I'm confused why it is still not working and updating my UI.  Here's my code below:

ViewModelBase Class:

```vb
#Region "INotifyPropertyChanged Members"
Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
Protected Overridable Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
    VerifyPropertyName(propertyName)
    Dim handler As PropertyChangedEventHandler = PropertyChangedEvent
    If handler IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim e = New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)
        handler(Me, e)
    End If
End Sub
#End Region
```

MainWindowViewModel Class:

```vb
Public Class MainWindowViewModel
    Inherits ViewModelBase

    Private Shared _coreInfoData As ObservableCollection(Of Person)
    Public Shared Property CoreInfoData() As ObservableCollection(Of Person)
        Get
            Return _coreInfoData
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of Person))
            _coreInfoData = value
        End Set

    Public Sub Main()
        If CoreInfoData IsNot Nothing Then
            CoreInfoData.Clear()
        End If
        CoreInfoData = GetRecords()
    End Sub
```

The GetRecords function is a call to a database that gets the most recent set of records available.

In my view, I'm actually binding to a CollectionViewSource and binding that to a datagrid:

```xaml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Path=CoreInfoData, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Key="cvs">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <dat:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="GroupId"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The `Person` class has properties `LastName` and `FirstName` (amoung others).  As I understand it, if the ObservableCollection itself changes - like what I do by clearning and filling it back up, it should automatically fire the INPC event, but my DataGrid doesn't seem to refresh the second time around.  Any ideas would be really helpful.

Thanks!

****EDIT****
Here's how I wound up solving the problem:

Public Shared Property CoreInfoData() As ObservableCollection(Of Person)

```vb
Public Shared Property CoreInfoData() As ObservableCollection(Of Person)
    Get
        Return _coreInfoData
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of Person))
        If _coreInfoData Is Nothing Then
            'get data
             _coreInfoData = value
        Else
             'refresh data
             _coreInfoData.Clear()
              For i = 0 To value.Count - 1
                    _coreInfoData.Add(value(i))
              Next
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

The First time the Set Method is called it will create a new _coreInfoData variable.  Subsequent calls will replace the existing one by clear it's entire contents and looping through each item to add it back into the collection.
Thanks to Clemens, Dan Busha, and Charleh (and others) for their helpful comments!

Comment: You are correct in your assumption - the list should change if the collection changes. This of course does not extend to property changes on objects within the collection (e.g. if FirstName changes it won't update). To do that you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your child objects and raise the event the interface exposes with the name of the changed property.

Comment: When you say 'second time around' what do you mean?

Comment: For all intents and purposes this should work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx - this bit: `If the source collection implements the INotifyCollectionChanged interface, the changes raised by the CollectionChanged event are propagated to the views.`

Comment: Your assertion "Observable Collections should automatically implement INPC" is incorrect: `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, which has a different function entirely.

Comment: Good spot - yes I got mixed up between the two interfaces too :)

Comment: @ CharlehAs the program runs, it periodically needs to refresh straight from the database.  On Startup, I grab the set of records with `GetRecords` and save to `CoreInfoData` and bind that to the DataGrid.  This works fine.  When I call `GetRecords` again to save over `CoreIndoData` it doesn't refresh the

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No PropertyChanged event will be raised automatically simply because the type of a property is `ObservableCollection`. You would have to raise it in the setter:

```
Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of Person)) 
    _coreInfoData = value
    OnPropertyChanged("CoreInfoData")
End Set
```

Comment: Are you sure that's correct - I thought changes to the ObservableCollection itself (such as an add/remove/clear) should automatically raise change events? e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Comment: Add/Remove/Clear *will* raise a change event, but if you do `CoreInfoData = new ObservableCollection(...)` then you're *not* changing the existing collection itself, you're replacing it.

Comment: @Charleh There are no changes to an ObservableCollection, there is a *new* ObservableCollection by `_coreInfoData = value`. And *if there were* changes to the ObservableCollection, it would fire a [INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged.aspx) event, not a PropertyChanged event.

Comment: Ah yes missed that - I saw the .Clear() and my eyes didn't go much further :) assumed was filling the collection rather than assigning it

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're assigning a value to your ObservableCollection which doesn't change your collection it replaces it. Either raise a PropertyChanged event for for the CoreInfoData property or add the items one by one from the `set` value to the ObservableCollection (the ObservableCollection should manage the raising of the PropertyChanged event for you).

Comment: As a sample, I tried to remove a the first line in the setter, but now the grid doesn't refresh: `Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of Person))`    `If _coreInfoData Is Nothing Then`    `_coreInfoData = value`       `Else _coreInfoData.RemoveAt(0)`  End If End Set End Property

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) with [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx).

ObservableCollection does implement INotifyPropertyChanged, this is used to fire the event for properties like Count and the indexer Item[]. It does not extend to the functionality you require it to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

first - why is your collection Shared/static?

when working with ObservableColelction then usually you create a instance just once and use clear, add remove.

if you wanna set a new instance like you did in your setter you have to call OnPropertyChanged("CoreInfoData") too.

but i would prefer clear and add

```
    CoreInfoData.Clear()
    CoreInfoData.AddRange(GetRecords())
```

Comment: .AddRange is a simply extension methode, which calls .Add for every item

Comment: @blindmeis, could you kindly elaborate on creating an instance of my collection.  I took off the shared modifier and it stopped binding to the datagrid, so somewhere in my code I've worked myself into a situation where I need it although I'd like to avoid it if possible

Comment: Also, I only have an `add` method available to my CoreInfoData.  Is the .AddRange an extension method you wrote yourself, or is available somewhere?  Basically it just loops through each item in the collection and calls .Add on each indiviually I take it.

Comment: @hades do you read comments? i wrote thats a simple extension method!