# XAML custom collection binding async collection update

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have a custom class inheriting from `ObservableCollection` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` (i.e. the custom class also has properties) that serves as a `Collection<T>` where `T` *also* inherits from `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public class CustomCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged where T: INotifyPropertyChanged {
private string _name;
public string Name {
    get {
        return _name;
    }
    set {
        if (_name != value) {
            _name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
}

private int _total;
public int Total {
    get {
        return _total;
    }
    set {
        if (_total != value) {
            _total = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Total");
        }
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName) {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (null != handler) {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And `T` item class:

```
public class DataItem : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string _fname;
    public string Fname {
        get {
            return _fname;
        }
        set {
            if (value != _fname) {
                _fname = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Fname");
            }
        }
    }

    private int_value;
    public int Value {
        get {
            return _value;
        }
        set {
            if (value != _value) {
                _value = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName) {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And the `ViewModel`:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    private readonly IService _dataService;

    private bool _isLoading;
    public bool IsLoading {
        get {
            return _isLoading;
        }
        private set {
            _isLoading = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsLoading");
        }
    }

    private CustomCollection<DataItem> _items;
    public CustomCollection<DataItem> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
        set
        {
            _items= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }

    public ViewModel(IService dataService) {
        _dataService = dataService;
    }

    public void Refresh() {
        if (!this.IsLoading) {
            this.IsLoading = true;

            _dataService.RefreshData(
                this, (error) => {
                    if (error != null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    if (!IsInDesignMode)
                        this.IsLoading = false;
                }
            );
        }
    }
    public void GetData() {
        if (Games == null) {
            Games = new CustomCollection<DataItem>();
        } else {
            Games.Clear();
        }

        if (!this.IsLoading) {
            this.IsLoading = true;

            _dataService.GetData(
                this, (error) => {
                    if (error != null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    if (!IsInDesignMode)
                        this.IsLoading = false;
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

And I have bound the `CustomCollection<T>` to a control in my View (xaml). Everything works fine initially, upon navigating to the page, the `ViewModel` calls for a `DataService` to retrieve the data and populate the `CustomCollection<T>`. However, when refreshing the data, the View is **not** updated until **all** the data has been iterated over and refreshed/updated!

Here is the code for the refresh/updated (keep in mind, I'm retrieving the data via a web service, and for the purposes of testing have just manually updated the `Value` property in `DataItem` at each passover of the `CustomCollection<T>`):

```
public async RefreshData(ViewModel model, Action<Exception> callback) {
    if (model.Items == null) return;

    // ... retrieve data from web service here (omitted) ...

    foreach (DataItem item in retrievedItems) { // loop for each item in retrieved items
        DataItem newItem = new DataItem() { Fname = item.Fname, Value = item.Value };
        if (model.Items.contains(newItem)) { // override for .Equals in CustomCollection<T> allows for comparison by just Fname property
            model.Items[model.Items.IndexOf(newItem)].Value += 10; // manual update
        } else {
            model.Items.Add(newItem);
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // 1 second pause to "see" each item updated sequentially...
    }
    callback(null);
}
```

So in summary, how can I make it so updating `Value` of my `DataItem` will *instantly* reflect in the View, given my current setup of `CustomCollection<DateItem>`? Something to do with `async` perhaps? I mean, when `Sleep(1000)` gets called, the UI does **not** hang, maybe this has something to do with it?

Any ideas on how to fix this? As you might have guessed, this issue is also present when first retrieving the data (but is barely noticeable as data is retrieved/processed during the navigation to the View).

**Note: I'm using the [MVVMLight Toolkit](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).**

Thanks.

Comment: For the record: ObservableCollection<T> already implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Thanks Willem, are you sure? According this comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/11847879/2714911 it does not?

Comment: Also according to that comment it does. Also according to the MSDN and Reflector ;)

Comment: Ah sorry, skimmed quickly on the go and misread!

Comment: The only loop I see in your example is the one that maps the data returned from the service to your model items. But that logic should be very fast (the sleep notwithstanding). So I don't see the point in worrying about whether the UI is updated one item at a time or all at once. Is there something about the `retrievedItems` result from the service that you haven't mentioned? Is iterating that object slow?

Comment: Also, when you write "UI does not hang", do you mean that's the behavior you desire? Or that _now_ you're able to refresh the data without the UI hanging? The latter would seem odd to me...if it's the case, you should be more specific about how you're calling the `Refresh()` method, i.e. why it's not being called from the UI thread now.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Regarding your first comment, the web service will return _all_ data and iterate over it, mapping them to objects in the Collection. This process is not slow, so really this question is a little bit of a nitpick. Really I was just trying to prepare for future expansion of my program which might require expensive operations upon iteration. Regarding your second comment, the UI not hanging is the desired behavior, so that's a non-issue.